# Tokyo Japan vs. Tokyo, Japan vs. Tokyo, Japan,

Tags: punctuation, commas

Could someone tell me which one of the following sentences is correct?

> 1. I will travel to Tokyo Japan next month.

or

> 2. I will travel to Tokyo, Japan next month.

or

> 3. I will travel to Tokyo, Japan, next month.

Comment: I think **I will travel to Tokyo next month** is enough since Tokyo is inside Japan and I don't think there isn't another 'Tokyo' *somewhere*.

Comment: Although, I think you would choose "Tokyo, Japan." in terms of writing.

Comment: I'd have thought ***Tokyo*** is sufficiently well-known that no-one would ever need to explicitly specify the country. Which implies that *semantically*, the specific form being queried here isn't exactly the same as the most common example where it ***is*** necessary to disambiguate the reference - ***Paris, Texas.*** I see some justification for not including the comma with *that* one, because it's effectively a necessary disambiguating part of the name (like ***John Smith***, although there's also ***Smith, John***). But with Tokyo it's just an optional extra bit of background information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Purdue OWL page "[Extended Rules for Commas](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/commas/extended_rules_for_commas.html),"

> Use commas to set off all geographical names, items in dates (except the month and day), addresses (except the street number and name), and titles in names.
>
> - Birmingham, Alabama, gets its name from Birmingham, England.
> - July 22, 1959, was a momentous day in his life. Who lives at 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington, DC?

Note that the OWL puts a comma before *and after* the name of the geographic region (Alabama) in the first example (as well as the year in the second example).

So, the punctuation that the Purdue OWL would recommend would be

> I will travel to Tokyo, Japan, next month.

That said, I admit that I very frequently see things like "I will travel to Tokyo, Japan next month" (with no comma after "Japan").

Comment: What style guide is Purdue following here, I wonder?  Because to my knowledge, in AmE, "...Tokyo, Japan next month" without the comma is strongly preferred.

Answer (score 3):

The correct option is:

> I will travel to Tokyo, Japan next month

Locations and addresses are generally expressed as a list of items, from most specific / local to most general / global; for instance "10 Downing Street, London, England".

In this case "Tokyo, Japan" would only be needed if there was a chance of confusing it with some other place called "Tokyo", which is unlikely, so the normal phrasing would be simply:

> I will travel to Tokyo next month

A common example where it used is "Paris, Texas" as opposed to "Paris, France" (with "Paris" on its own most likely to refer to the capital of France, unless you're already in Texas).

There is also a song:

> New York, New York (So Good They Named It Twice)

Here, "New York" is the name of both a city and a state, so "New York, New York" means "New York City, New York State".

Comment: You most often see e.g. 'Paris, France' from US sources, since, generally people outside that country assume you mean the capital of France. Sometimes satirised as 'Rome, Iddly'.

Answer (score 1):

The use of "city, region" is mostly confined to American English.

In American English, it is very common to disambiguate the name of a city by using the name of the state.  This is necessary because there are often many cities with the same name in different states. This pattern is required for postal addresses, and so expressions like "Chicago, Illinois" are used, even though there is no real chance of confusing it with any other place called Chicago.

If you are using American English then "... to Tokyo, Japan, next month" is okay.  It would be understood in British English, but would be considered a Americanism.

Of course there is only one significant city called Tokyo, so there is no need to say Japan at all.  But if you wanted to in British English then  "Tokyo in Japan" is better.

However expressions like "London, England" are not idiomatic in British English.

Comment: As noted elsewhere, there's only one Tokyo. However, if you were traveling to "London, Ontario"... then you'd probably better specify!

Comment: That would be the London in Canada.